# Organizing spring-mvc URL endpoints so they remain refactorable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I'm often working on very large web applications that use spring-mvc and I find that it becomes increasingly difficult to organize my URL endpoints in a way that keeps them refactorable. By convention, my controllers might look like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = ProtocolController.ROOT_MAPPING)
public class ProtocolController extends BaseController {

    public static final String ROOT_MAPPING = "/protocol";

    @RequestMapping(value="/management", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView management(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I might have a view somewhere else in the application that has a link back to the "management" page so that view has to build the URL. In my view I can access the context path via the model (context path was injected into model by `BaseController`), I can access the next segment of the URL via `ProtocolController.ROOT_MAPPING` but then the last part of the URL is just a regular ol' String. My choice of view technology is a custom in-house solution that involves writing raw Java to generate HTML:

```
String url = model.get("contextPath") + ProtocolController.ROOT_MAPPING + "/management"
```

The problem is that if I ever change the "/management" endpoint, I can't find all the places in my code that reference it. I suppose I could replace the string literal with a `static final` String just like I do with `ROOT_MAPPING` but is there a cleaner way? Are there any known design patterns for organizing/referencing endpoints?

Comment: What I can think of is similar to what you are already doing. But instead declaring the static variables in very class, I will put them in a central class(may be named Constants) so that I don't have to scan entire project to find those static variables.

Comment: Which version of Spring is being used? If you are using spring 4.x then you can leverage MvcUriComponentsBuilder and there is corresponding Tag library. Let me know the version and i can elaborate few things on the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only using Spring 3.2.13. Regardless, I'll take a look at MvcUriComponentsBuilder and see if I can learn a thing or two.